# Getting the instance of EnvDTE.Debugger in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, envdte

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio Integration Package project which will display data from the debugger.
So I found the EnvDTE namespace, that looks to give me the needed classes and methods.
According to the documentation for VS2005, the following code should be used to get an instance of the debugger:

```
EnvDTE.Debugger _debugger;
_debugger = EnvDTE.DTE.Debugger;
```

But this generates an error in VS2010 - An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'EnvDTE._DTE.Debugger.get'

How can I interrogate the debugger in VS2010?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access DTE's debugger from a VS Package, call [GetService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package.getservice.aspx) on your `Package` object, as in:

```
DTE2 dteInstance = (DTE2) _package.GetService(typeof(SDTE));
Debugger4 dteDebugger = (Debugger4) dteInstance.Debugger;
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this code compiles. But dteInstance is always null (I tried also ' DTE dteInstance = (DTE)this.GetService(typeof(SApplicationObject));' which, according to MSDN, used to get DTE's instance - also doesn't work. Do you have any idea what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. but googling I found this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/1a827bc5-657a-466f-88a2-909865de3ec2/ and that links to more threads on msdn forums on the same situation you're describing

Comment: I know that this is a pretty old question but the code should be `Debugger4 dteDebugger = (Debugger4) dteInstance.Debugger;` instead of `Debugger4 dteDebugger = (Debugger4) dteInstance;`. Due to the code the dteDebugger variable will always be null.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe better way would be create Debugger visualizer, look at the Mole AFAIK it's by far most capable debugger visualizer and for old version source is available

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-2010/mole-for-visual-studio/

Comment: thank you, but visualizer doen't fit my needs. Is there an option to connect to EnvDTE's debugger?